# Linq compared to IComparer

Tags: linq, icomparer

I have seen this class that looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides an internal structure to sort the query parameter
    /// </summary>
    protected class QueryParameter
    {
        public QueryParameter(string name, string value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Value { get; private set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comparer class used to perform the sorting of the query parameters
    /// </summary>
    protected class QueryParameterComparer : IComparer<QueryParameter>
    {
        public int Compare(QueryParameter x, QueryParameter y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name 
                ? string.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) 
                : string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
        }
    }
```

Then there is a call later in the code that does the sort:

```
parameters.Sort(new QueryParameterComparer());
```

which all works fine. 
I decided that it was a waste of time creating a QueryParameter class that only had name value and it would probably be better to use Dictionary. With the dictionary, rather than use the Sort(new QueryParameterComparer()); I figured I could just do this:

```
parameters.ToList().Sort((x, y) => x.Key == y.Key ? string.Compare(x.Value, y.Value) : string.Compare(x.Key, y.Key));
```

The code compiles fine, but I am unsure whether it is working because the list just seems to output in the same order it was put in.
So, can anyone tell me if I am doing this correctly or if I am missing something simple?

Cheers
/r3plica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<T>.Sort` method is not part of LINQ.

You can use `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` extension methods before calling ToList():

```
parameters = parameter.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ThenBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would a SortedDictionary eliminate the need for doing any sorting?

Answer (score 2):

From your code, I surmise that `parameters` is your dictionary, and you're calling

```
parameters.ToList().Sort(...);
```

and then carrying on using `parameters`.

`ToList()` creates a new list; you are then sorting this list and *discarding it*. You're not sorting `parameters` at all, and in fact you *can't* sort it because it's a dictionary.

What you need is something along the lines of

```
var parametersList = parameters.ToList();
parametersList.Sort(...);
```

where `...` is the same sort as before.

You could also do

```
var parametersList = parameters.OrderBy(...).ToList();
```

which is a more LINQ-y way of doing things.

It may even be appropriate to just do e.g.

```
foreach(var kvp in parameters.OrderBy(...))
```

(or however you plan on using the sorted sequence) if you're *using* the sorted seqence more often than you're *changing* the dictionary (i.e. there's no point caching a sorted version because the original data changes a lot).

---

Another point to note - a dictionary can't contain duplicate keys, so there's no point checking `x.Key == y.Key` any more - you just need to sort via `(x, y) => string.Compare(x.Key, y.Key)`

I'd be careful here, though - by the look of it, the original code *did* support duplicate keys, so by switchnig to a dictionary you might be breaking something.

Comment: Nice explaination. I was aware of the no duplicates, but that is exactly what I need because OAuth doesn't allow duplicate keys

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary are only equivalent to two hash map, and allow you to access to any alement (given the key) with costant time O(1) (because the make a lookup search on an hashtable).

So if you would order the elements because you intended to do a dicotomic search later, you do not need that you should use directly dictionary (or if you would query for both the value in dictionary you could use a couple of dictionary with the same elements but switching key value pairs).

As somebody write before me, if you question is how to order a list with linq you should work with linq and with orderby thenby.